# Conditionally inserting data into an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Alright, can someone help me how to properly iterate a dynamic size array?
Here's what I mean:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 15, 2] # <= there are three 2 inside my_array
```

Then I would like to add "good" everytime the iteration hit integer 2, I tried several method but not find the way, here's the best method I've tried(still not resulting in what I want)

```
# First Method
for i in 0..(my_array.length - 1)
 my_array.insert(i + 1, "good") if my_array[i] == 2
end

p my_array # => [1, 2, "good", 3, 4, 2, "good", 5, 15, 2] 

# Second Method
for i in 0..(my_array.length - 1)
 my_array[i + 1] = "good" if my_array[i] == 2
end

p my_array # => [1, 2, "good", 4, 2, "good", 15, 2, "good"]
```

The first method is not good because it's not showing "good" after the last 2, I guess this because the iteration could not reach the last integer 2(in the last array) and that is expected because the array size is changed bigger everytime "good" is inserted.

The second one is also bad, because I replace the data after every 2 with "good" string.
Now can someone point it out to me how can I doing this properly so I can produce it like this:

```
 p my_array # => [1, 2, "good", 3, 4, 2, "good", 5, 15, 2, "good"]
```

All "good" is added without replacing any data.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have a better time transforming this into a new array than modifying in-place:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 15, 2]

def add_good(a)
  a.flat_map do |value|
    case (value)
    when 2
      [ 2, 'good' ]
    else
      value
    end
  end
end

puts add_good(my_array).inspect
# => [1, 2, "good", 3, 4, 2, "good", 5, 15, 2, "good"]
```

The `flat_map` method is useful for situations where you want to create zero or more entries in the resulting array. `map` is a 1:1 mapping, `flat_map` is a 1:N.

It's also possible to make this much more generic:

```
def fancy_insert(a, insert)
  a.flat_map do |value|
    if (yield(value))
      [ value, insert ]
    else
      value
    end
  end
end

result = fancy_insert(my_array, 'good') do |value|
  value == 2
end

puts result.inspect
```

That way you can pass in an arbitrary block and value to be inserted.

Comment: For educational examples I try to make the logic as clear as possible. The ternary operator can be a bit confusing, plus also doesn't "scale" very well when you want to add additional cases.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, there's no need to create an additional array in the `else` branch of your `case` statement.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I can see the flat_map method is really good, I definetely use flat_map now, again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the `.each_with_index` method:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5]
arr.each_with_index {|e, i| arr.insert(i+1, "good") if e == 2}
```

Fast and furious.

Comment: Wow thanks with this, it helps me resolve my problems. Thank you very much =)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark it as Solution so it can be used by other people :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you can do it, using an Enumerator:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 15, 2]

enum = my_array.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 15, 2]:each>

my_array = []
loop do
  x = enum.next
  my_array << x
  my_array << "good" if x == 2
end
my_array
  #=> [1, 2, "good", 3, 4, 2, "good", 5, 15, 2, "good"]
```

[Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises a `StopInteration` exception when the enumerator is already on the last element. [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking the loop.  That's why you will often see `loop` used when stepping through an enumerator.